# ORA-01882: timezone region not found - Oracle ADF Web application

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, oracle11g, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I installed oracle 11g db on windows, and my jdeveloper (11.1.2.4.0 ) installed on ubuntu.
When I login to my application I get the following error:

java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01882: timezone region not found

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:462)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:405)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:931)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:481)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:205)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:548)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:202)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1110)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1488)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:2147)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:2091)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:320)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.setSessionTimeZone(PhysicalConnection.java:13052)
at oracle.jdbc.OracleConnectionWrapper.setSessionTimeZone(OracleConnectionWrapper.java:535)
```

on ubuntu, my timezone is Asia/Urumqi and on windows, oracle database session timezone is Asia/Urumqi, also windows server time zone is GMT+08:00.

What is the problem? Please, help me.

Answer (score 1):

set domain date in ( time zone in Date and time in control panel ) 
example : 
domain date : UTC +5:00:00:00
your pc-Date : UTC +3:00:00:00

set your pc-date same domain date

Answer (score 0):

Its a famous problem with JDev, follow the following steps:

1. Go Tools | Project Properties
2. Select Run/Debug, Double click on Default to Edit
3. Select Launch Settings and add the following unside 'Java option'

   -Duser.timezone="+06:00"
4. Restart JDeveloper

Comment: its not working with me as well
i tried to add the -Duser.timezone="+06:00" to the model project and to the viewcontroller project as well with no luck